# Creating a Caesar Cipher using for loops and if/else statements

Tags: python

I have to create a Caesar cipher for my class. The stipulations are that I can't import anything, and that I have to use for loops and if/else statements. I've gotten the code pretty close to completion, but am currently stuck. The program currently runs without throwing any error codes, but does not output the required answers. I've attached the code below. There are currently two issues that I'm seeking solutions for. Firstly, I wrote a if/else statement to wrap around the values if they are below 65 or above 96. This is all that's necessary as the output should be in all caps. However, this statement doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm not currently sure why this is. Secondly, the code adds a character to the output after each space. I've told the code to basically ignore spaces, so I have no idea why this is. For example: If my message was "Attack zerg at dawn" and my encoding key was "3", the output should be "DWWDFN CHUJ DW GDZQ", just capitalizing everything and shifting them by 3. However, I get "DWWDFN =]HUJ =DW =GDZQ". As you can see, it's mostly correct. I just can't seem to figure out the parts that aren't. Thanks for any assistance you're able to provide.

```
enter def caesar_cipher():
text = str.upper(input("Your message? "))
shift = int(input("Encoding key? "))
for i in range(0, len(text)):
    a = text[i]
    o = a.find(" ")
    if o == 0:
        print(" ", end='')
    p = a.find("'")
    if p == 0:
        print("'", end='')
    s = a.find("!")
    if s == 0:
        print("!", end='')
    d = a.find('"')
    if d == 0:
        print('"', end='')
    new = ord(str(a)) + shift
    if int(new) >= 97:
        new2 = int(new) - 26
        new3 = chr(int(new2))
    elif int(new) <= 64:
        new2 = int(new) + 26
        new3 = chr(int(new2))
    else:
        new3 = chr(int(new))
    print(new3, end='')


caesar_cipher()
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I have successfully completed the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of general comments:

- you're using a function, which is a good thing, but then the function is basically the whole program, including input, processing and output; generally, writing a function is a good idea if it has a clearly defined function, like 'computes the caesar cipher for a string'
- you're confusing print statements with the result of a function; although you may be required to print the output, it makes more sense to first compute a result and then print it in most cases; have your function return a result, then print that result
- you're checking if `a` is equal to `' '` by checking for the position of `' '` in `a`, but you can just `if a == ' '`
- you're checking `a` for four different values, but then end up doing the same thing four times, which is adding that value to the result; you can combine those easily
- even if `a` is one of those values, you still go and compute `new`, you need an `else` there (this actually answers your second question)
- you create several variables (`new`, `new2` and `new3`) even though you can combine most of those statements into a single one, or overwrite the variable's value if you need to; so, `new = 65 + 3` followed by `new2 = chr(new)` could have just as easily been `new = 65 + 3` followed by `new = chr(new)`, or just `new = chr(65 + 3)`
- `ord()` returns an `int` and `shift` is an `int`, so their sum is an `int` as well, no need to keep casting stuff to `int()`
- you had a small miscalculation in your edge cases, but that's a minor thing you would have found when testing the working code anyway

Applying all that to your code:

```
def caesar_cipher(text, shift):
    result = ''
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        a = text[i]
        if a in [' ', '\'', '!', '"']:
            result += a
        else:
            new = ord(str(a)) + shift
            if new > 90:
                new = chr(new - 26)
            elif new < 65:
                new = chr(new + 26)
            else:
                new = chr(new)
            result += new
    return result


def main():
    message = str.upper(input("Your message? "))
    key = int(input("Encoding key? "))
    print(caesar_cipher(message, key))


main()
```

Or, if you want to tell your teacher you got the answer on StackOverflow, submit this:

```
def caesar_cipher(text, shift):
    return ''.join(
        ch if ch in ' \'!"' else chr((ord(ch) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65) for ch in text
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I figured out that I could just use the ord value to exclude anything out of the range of capital letters, that way I don't have to find anything. The else statement you added was what finished my code. Thanks for taking the time to do this!

Comment: You're welcome - please accept the answer using the checkmark, if you feel you no longer need a better answer, so that it shows up as answered to others looking for questions to answer (or looking for correct answers) as well.

Answer (score 0):

does this answer your question

```
def encrypt(text,s):
result = ""
   # transverse the plain text
   for i in range(len(text)):
      char = text[i]
      # Encrypt uppercase characters in plain text
      
      if (char.isupper()):
         result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65)
      # Encrypt lowercase characters in plain text
      else:
         result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
      return result
#check the above function
text = "CEASER CIPHER DEMO"
s = 4

print "Plain Text : " + text
print "Shift pattern : " + str(s)
print "Cipher: " + encrypt(text,s)
```

Answer (score -1):

this does not really answer your question as i do not use a `for` loop or an `if` statement.

but with [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) you could do this pretty elegantly:

```
key = 3
plain = "Attack zerg at dawn"

# prepare the key
alpha_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key_tbl = str.maketrans(alpha_upper.lower(), alpha_upper[key:] + alpha_upper[:key])

# encrypt
cip = plain.lower().translate(key_tbl)
print(cip)  # DWWDFN CHUJ DW GDZQ
```

in this case `maketrans` will convert `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` to `"DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC"`.

Comment: As you indicate, this doesn't answer the question - it's merely a completely different way to solve a trivial problem

Comment: @Grismar yet as it is clearly a beginner question i think there is some merit in showing alternative ways to solve this.